# Dense sets because of that the union of two open sets is open

Tags: general-topology

if 1 and 2 were hypothetically speaking "the open sets of a topology" and 2,3 is a subset of x then does it make sense to say yet that 2,3 is dense in the elements because the union of 1 and 2 must be an open set / neighborhood of 1 which contains the element 2 in 2,3?? Or because 1 is an open set the whole time then there is a neighborhood without the elements 2,3....

Comment: If you mean $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$ are open sets, then $\{2,3\}$ is not dense because it doesn't intersect $\{1\}$.

Comment: I am confused of the one long sentence that is supposed to conway your question. Couldn't you use a larger amount of punctuation signs? How is it that  "the open set of x are 1 and 2", yet later "3 is an open set because...", followed by an explanation containing what I find as an unclear phrase "a topology which is dense in the others right"...

Comment: @robertisrael 1 and 2 are open sets so, 1,2 is open if I remember correctly....

Comment: @DanielImber thank you for your clarification about your personal condition

Comment: ... If you were not aware, you could use the edit button to clarify what you were asking. I see this is the third question you posted, the other two were already "closed as unclear what you're asking". I assume you have no algebraists at all in your university, given those two questions were in algebra?

Answer (score 1):

A set $A$ is dense in topological space $(X,\tau)$ iff $A \cap U $ is not empty for any non-empty open set $U$.

Comment: 1 and 2 are the open sets of the topology in my example, so the set 2,3 in the underlying space is supposed to be dense in the topological space because 1,2 is a neighborhood ( another open set of the topology because of the axioms ) of 1 and 2 that intersects with 2,3 is that true or false????

Comment: Please define your topology completely. Give us all the open sets and tell us why $\{2,3\}$ is dense.

Comment: okay then 1, 2, 1 and 2 are the open sets of a topological space and the half open set 2,3 is dense in the space because of 2 intersecting with the open set 1,2.

Comment: As already pointed out by Robert Israel it is not true that $\{2,3\}$ is dense. As long a$\{1\}$ is open this set cannot be dense.

Comment: Thanks I just noticed that because 1 is a neighborhood of itself..